# moving flutter sdk files between devices without internet

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have flutter installed on a device und updated to the latest version (Flutter 3.9.0-12.0) and I need to move it to another device but the main problem is that the other device have no connection to the internet, I tried to move the flutter SDK file to the other device but it is not working. is there any available solution

Comment: Try downloading the updated version of flutter SDK from the website and then install it on another device.

Comment: check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-Installation-Bundles

Comment: I'm trying it now

Comment: @pskink I tried to do so but I can't create any project on the offline device